# ¿Cómo puedo generar un array a partir de varias hojas en un libro de Excel con la gema rubyXL?

Tags: xml, excel, ruby, rubygems

Buen día compañeros,

Estoy leyendo un libro de Excel en formato **.xlsx** este tiene 6 hojas, cada hoja tiene un identificador de línea con sus respectivas cabeceras, es decir, se maneja un ID tipo base de datos por hoja ya que de la 2 a la 6 son complementos de la hoja 1, pero todos estos son opcionales, ¿qué significa? Que la página 3 puede estar o no asociada a la 1 ya que como he dicho son complementos.

La primera hoja es la cabecera de un documento tributario (factura, recibo, nota de crédito, nota de débito, etc.), la segunda hoja son sus items, la tercera es un complemento que indica si es de exportación o no la factura, la cuarta indica si es factura especial, la quinta indica si es una factura cambiaria, y la última indica si es una nota de crédito o débito. Cuando recorro la hoja número uno, verifico si tiene complementos, es decir, si su ID se repite en las otras hojas (que por lo menos debe estar en una) y así amarro los complementos a la principal, con esto debo crear un array o hash para poder luego obtener sus valores y setearlos en un template de XML.

De antemano les agradezco

Saludos cordiales,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solucionado**

Lo realizado fue que mediante un método **each_with_index** iteré sobre la primera hoja del libro mientras al mismo tiempo obtenía un índice (index), para obviar los encabezados puse un **if** para verificar que el índice fuera mayor a la posición 0 (la primera fila), con el índice comparé este con la primera posición de cada hoja obviando la primera fila (encabezados), si este era igual entonces entraba dentro de un **each** por cada hoja.

Previo a esto hice un hash para integrar todo el documento, que se compone de varios arrays por cada hoja, conforme iba iterando tuve que mapear manualmente cada columna.

Un ejemplo de lo realizado:

```
require 'rubyXL'

libro = RubyXL::Parser::parse '/ubicacion/del/archivo/excel.xlsx'

$dte = Array.new

libro[0].each_with_index do |fila, index|
  if index > 0
    id_root = fila.cells[0].value

    dte_hoja2 = Array.new
    dte_hoja3 = Array.new
    dte_hoja4 = Array.new
    dte_hoja5 = Array.new
    dte_hoja6 = Array.new

    libro[1].each do |filaHoja2|
      if id_root == filaHoja2.cells[0].value
        hoja2_excel = {idCol1: filaHoja2.cells[0].value,
                       col2: filaHoja2.cells[1].value
        }
        dte_hoja2 << hoja2_excel
      end
    end

    libro[2].each do |filaHoja3|
      if id_root == filaHoja3.cells[0].value
        hoja3_excel = {idCol1: filaHoja3.cells[0].value,
                       col2: filaHoja3.cells[1].value
        }
        dte_hoja3 << hoja3_excel
      end
    end

    libro[3].each do |filaHoja4|
      if id_root == filaHoja4.cells[0].value
        hoja4_excel = {idCol1: filaHoja4.cells[0].value,
                       col2: filaHoja4.cells[1].value
        }
        dte_hoja4 << hoja4_excel
      end
    end

    libro[4].each do |filaHoja5|
      if id_root == filaHoja5.cells[0].value
        hoja5_excel = {idCol1: filaHoja5.cells[0].value,
                       col2: filaHoja5.cells[1].value
        }
        dte_hoja5 << hoja5_excel
      end
    end

    libro[5].each do |filaHoja6|
      if id_root == filaHoja6.cells[0].value
        hoja6_excel = {idCol1: filaHoja6.cells[0].value,
                       col2: filaHoja6.cells[1].value
        }
        dte_hoja6 << hoja6_excel
      end
    end

    dte_libro = {idCol1: id_root,
                 col2: hoja.cells[1].value,
                 col3: hoja.cells[2].value,
                 hoja2: dte_hoja2,
                 hoja3: dte_hoja3,
                 hoja4: dte_hoja4,
                 hoja5: dte_hoja5
    }
  $dte << dte_libro
 end
end
```